# Colorbox not loading - simple code.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I'm sure this is very simple. I have gotten colorbox to work before, but when I started trying it on a new site, it just won't load!

I have the jquery and colorbox files in the same directory as this html file along with the colorbox.css and images in the images folder from example 2. And I mean, it's just supposed to load the colorbox when the document is ready, but it isn't. I must be missing something very dumb, please tell me if you see anything. Thanks!

PS. I do have internet connection to get the library from the site, and I've tried it just linking to the file in the directory to no avail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
MAITRE U

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.colorbox({html:'<p>TEST TEST</p>'});
                           });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same Question:<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383277/why-is-colorbox-not-loading-properly> Please refer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gPJay/1/). Use view page source on your html page and make sure that the colorbox css and js files are loaded properly. Finally try with the js file from the colorbox site itself

Comment: I'm baffled since it works there, and it looks like my css and js files are loaded correctly. I did try it again linking just to the file I downloaded, and still no colorbox pops up. Here is an image that shows the files in my directory and how I link to them:

Comment: http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/3351/colorbox.jpg

I have also checked out the solutions from that other page. I am extremely baffled.

Comment: can you try it any other browser and make sure that you are not making any trivial errors like disabling the javascript in the browser

Comment: It is the strangest thing, I took a break from it and loaded it up and it worked finally. Some awry setting, perhaps. Anyway, thanks all for your help/hints in such a trivial problem.